# How to update dom element to select option value in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

What's the best way to update the text with a DOM element, in this case `<span>` to the value of a `<select>` `<option>` on change in vanilla JS?

To give context, in my case this is to update the price shown in the `<span></span>` to the corresponding value of the selection.

```
<select name="classesPW" id="classesPW">
    <option value="5">1</option>
    <option value="9">2</option>
    <option value="12.50">3</option>
    <option value="16">4</option>
    <option value="19">5</option>
    <option value="22">6</option>
    <option value="25">7</option>
    <option value="28">8</option>
    <option value="31">9</option>
    <option value="34">10</option>
    <option value="37">11</option>
    <option value="40">12</option>
</select>

<h3>
    <span>£</span>
    <span id="pwTotal"> [[value here]] </span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Also there's no `<span>value here</span>` in your snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use querySelector to get your elements, assign a change event listener to the select, and then retrieve the value of the selected item and put it to the span via innerHTML.

Working example :

```js
let select = document.querySelector('#classesPW')
let sp = document.querySelector('#pwTotal')

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  sp.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
})
```

```html
<select name="classesPW" id="classesPW">
    <option value="5">1</option>
    <option value="9">2</option>
    <option value="12.50">3</option>
    <option value="16">4</option>
    <option value="19">5</option>
    <option value="22">6</option>
    <option value="25">7</option>
    <option value="28">8</option>
    <option value="31">9</option>
    <option value="34">10</option>
    <option value="37">11</option>
    <option value="40">12</option>
</select>

<h3>
    <span>£</span>
    <span id="pwTotal">5</span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Ahh that's so simple, I was really overcomplicating it in my head. Thank you that makes perfect sense.

Comment: `sp.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value` I didn't know about the `selectedIndex` prop! Save the hassle of looping through the options to figure out which is selected. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var selectElement = document.getElementById('classesPW');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', function(e){
 var selection = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById('pwTotal').innerText = selection;
});
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code. Also, without the html part your snippet won't work.